# How to put php into html a href

Tags: php

i have this php script

```
$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="/this/story">Read More</a>';
```

and i wanna change that a href ------ "/this/story"  ---- with

```
<a href="clanok/ echo urlencode($row['id']); ?>/ echo createSlug($row['title']); ?>" title="">Read more</a>
```

I never put php tags in html i always do it separate (not mixing php and html).

Please tell me the difference between '" in a href when mixing php and html.

I wanna something like this, but this have so many errors :D

```
$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="clanok/ echo urlencode($row['id']); ?>/ echo createSlug($row['title']); ?>" title="">Read More</a>';
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?  What isn't working?

Comment: The quote usage seems correct. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I can´t replace that bottom ahref with that first ahref because i never use a href in php script.

Comment: The bottom script has `href` right here -> `<a href`.

Comment: @Forlis: .... Did you *try*?  What's *actually stopping* you from modifying your code, other than the fact that you haven't done it before?

Comment: Well yes with update you have many errors. Look at the highlighting. You also are already in PHP. So `<?php `s are not needed, not the `echo`s. Concatenate.

Comment: Yes i try, but it always give me some errors, cause i dont know how use ' or " in a href, when it is in php script. I dont know the diference between ' and ".

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use `<?php echo` and `?>`.

```
$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '))."... <a href=\"clanok/". urlencode($row['id'])."/".createSlug($row['title'])."\" title=\"\">Read more</a>";
```

The above should work for you.

Comment: To elaborate on this for the OP... You don't need to "put PHP in HTML in PHP".  You're already in the context of PHP code and you're just building a string variable (which happens to contain HTML, but PHP doesn't care about that).  Just concatenate the parts of the string that are used to build the whole string.